# what url should be used to select an imap mailbox using libcurl

Tags: imap, libcurl

When the **"Select Inbox"** custom command is issued, the imap server sends back statistics about the **Inbox** mailbox, specifically (Number of emails, number of recent emails, first unseen seq no, UiValididy, NextUid) among other things.

The maintaining team discourages the usage of **curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, qs);**. Is there an URL string that could perform the same function as **"Select INBOX"** **(i.e. imap://imapserver/Inbox(I do not know what else follows)**

Any help is so appreciated.